# Making a file through python3

Tags: python, file, terminal

Basically for my test tomorrow I have to Create a file named "answers." In it, place the questions provided along with the correct answers, do I just run vim on my terminal and type it within that? Or does it need to be done another way?

Comment: It doesn't fit to StackOverflow!

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you want to create a file in python you can simply open a file with mode 'w', like: open('answers.txt', 'w'). It will automatically create the file for you if it doesn't exist.

Comment: like basically i need to be able to create a file to where I can type in questions and answers, then send it in for my teacher to be able to open and read

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be a python question, so use can use any of the following commands if they work:

```
emacs answers.txt
vi answers.txt
vim answers.txt
nano answers.txt
```

However, if you have to do it through python, use an `open('answers.txt', 'w')`, and it will automatically create a file giving you write privileges. Later, you can type into your Spotlight: `answers.txt`, and it will appear

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("answers", "w") as outf:
    outf.write("this is a question\n")
    outf.write("this is an answer\n")
```

Or just use a text editor (although I don't see why that would be a Python question).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, why go the way of a text editor. In Python, as requested:

```
f = open("answers.", "w")
f.write("Type your answers between these quotes")
f.close()
```

In reality - just ask the teacher/professor.

Answer (score 0):

This is not appropriate for this forum. Just open an editor, type in your questions and answers and send it to him.

Comment: did you not read.... it has to be done through python......

Comment: @user3331010 You do not mention python in your question. That is why we asked about this. You just say you have to create the file but do not explicitly say create using python. If you do have to use Python, is there something more than just writing strings to a file? For example must the questions and answers be two parts of a list or tuple or something more?